# By clicking "mailto" link jumps to top of the page

Tags: javascript, browser, scroll, mailto

I used this javaScript code to add "mailto" to an element on my page:

```
document.getElementById("mailTo").href = "mailto:?subject=look at this website&body=Hi,I found this website and thought you might like it "+ document.location.href
```

Now, when I click the link, it opens the email just fine, but it also jumps to the top of the page suddenly, can anyone tell me why that is happening? or how I can stop that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove the original onClick event from the link, and create a new function to handle the click. That should prevent the unwanted behavior from a regular a-tag, which I guess that your button is?

Something along the lines of;

```
document.getElementById('mailTo').removeAttribute("onclick");

document.getElementById('mailTo').onclick = function(){
    location.href = "mailto:?subject=look at this website&body=Hi,I found this website and thought you might like it "+ document.location.href;
};
```

The documentation on "preventDefault();" here could also prove valuable:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: if i could ask again, this seems to work on some instances of my website and not others .. for some reason it's stopped working at all recently, do you have any idea why it would do that? i've also tried replacing removeAttribute with an e.preventDefault() then adding the mailto onclick but it still jumps to the top of the page :/

Comment: you could try changing the <a> tag to a <button>. It has different behaviour, which should not do anything on-click by default. Then use just the above .onclick function on that button